# JavaScript/jQuery code optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JavaScript and jQuery and currently I'm dealing with following code:

```
  $("#hrefBlur0").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur0").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
  $("#hrefBlur1").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur1").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
  $("#hrefBlur2").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur2").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
  $("#hrefBlur3").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur3").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
  $("#hrefBlur4").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur4").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
  $("#hrefBlur5").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur5").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
  $("#hrefBlur6").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur6").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
  $("#hrefBlur7").hover(function() {
    $("#imgBlur7").toggleClass("blur frame");
  });
```

The code is supposed to remove blur effect from an image while I hoover a cursor on a href link on the website.  I'm wondering if I can do it faster, with fewer lines of code. 
I tried:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $("#hrefBlur" + i).hover(function() {
      $("#imgBlur" + i).toggleClass("blur frame");
    });
  }
```

But that code doesn't work.

Here's the JS fiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/21fq8cat/1/)

Comment: Replace all those ids with a class?

Comment: We need to see your HTML to see how the `#hrefX` elements relate to the `#imgX` elements, as I'm sure it's possible to simplify this using DOM traversal and no ugly concatenated selectors in a loop

Comment: Closure is the issue here

Comment: Any reason you don't just use CSS?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan here's the JS fiddle I created. The code is supposed to make a navbar [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21fq8cat/1/)

Comment: In that case @Sycraw already has your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a class to the elements and select that class, for example let's say you want to use "blurMeContainer" for the container, you can do something like this:

```
$(".blurMeContainer").hover(function(el){
$(this).find("img").toggleClass("blur frame");
});
```

The trick is that you must be aware that jQuery applies the events to the element, so inside the events function, the "this" accessor is the element involved in the event, than you can use the $ function in the selector in order to have his corrispective jQuery element, and then you can use "find" method to find any img tag inside the jQuery element. Obviously this could work only if you have a single image in the container, if you need to identify only one image in a set of images inside a single container, assign a class to that image (IE: "blurMe") and change the code in this way:

```
    $(".blurMeContainer").hover(function(el){
$(this).find(".blurMe").toggleClass("blur frame");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `attributeStartsWith` selector , that Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string:

```
$('a[id^="hrefBlur"]').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggleClass("blur frame");
});
```

Here's working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ersamrow/hb6n3jdh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Although doing what your after can be done with JQuery.  I personally think it's the wrong tool for the Job.

CSS, will do all this for you, in a much simpler way.  No Javascript needed.  With the added benefit of the browser optimisations.

```css
.blurme {
  filter: blur(3px);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 2s, filter 1s;
}

.blurme:hover { 
  filter: none;
  color: red;  
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span class="blurme">One</span>
<span class="blurme">Two</span>
<span class="blurme">Three</span>
<span class="blurme">Four</span>
<span class="blurme">Five</span>
<span class="blurme">Six</span>
<br>

<img class="blurme" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg">
<img class="blurme" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg">
<img class="blurme" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg">
```